# Lerch-$\small \zeta(\varphi,0,-n)$ of integer *n* purely real and imaginary ($\small \zeta_\varphi (-n)^2 $ is real) for $\small n \ge 2$?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, special-functions, zeta-functions, eulerian-numbers

Are the  [Lerch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function)-$\zeta(\varphi,0,-n) $ of integer *n* (for shortness I use the notation of my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49584) $\small \zeta_\varphi(-n)$) periodically purely real and imaginary: $\zeta_\varphi (-n)^2 $ is real, ($ n \ge 2$) ? And how to prove this?

I've a strange observation of periodicity which I would like to explain/derive/prove  analytically.

---

Consider the triangle of eulerian numbers **E** (ideally of infinite size, row and col-indices beginning at zero, with elements $ \small e_{r,c}$)

$ \qquad E = \small 
\begin{array} {rrrrr}
 1 & . & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & 0 & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & . & . & . \\
 1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & . & . \\
 1 & 11 & 11 & 1 & 0 & . \\
 1 & 26 & 66 & 26 & 1 & 0
 \end{array}  $

Assume some angular parameter $\varphi$, the associated complex number from the unit-circle $z=z_\varphi= \exp(i \varphi ) \qquad z \ne 1 $, $ \small {\varphi \over \pi} $ not necessarily rational.

Now consider the Eulerian polynomials, whose coefficients are taken from a row of **E**,
 $ \small E(z,r) = \sum_{c=0}^\infty ( e_{r,c} \cdot z^c ) $

Then compute $ \small \zeta_\varphi(-n) = {z \over (1-z)} \cdot E(z,n) \cdot (1-z)^{-n} $ .

**Observation**: I observe, that for $n>2$ the $ \small \zeta_\varphi(-n) $ lie either on the real or on the imaginary axis, in other words $ \small \zeta_\varphi(-n) ^2 $ are real..

**Q**: I seem to be missing just the key idea, so my question here is, how I could derive that behave analytically, given the description via the Eulerian triangle.

**Addendum/Generalization**: While it was already surprising, that this works with *rational* roots *z* of the complex unit, it seems to me even more interesting, that the observation holds for *arbitrary* $ \small \varphi \ne 0 $ and $ \small z_\varphi = \exp(I \cdot \varphi) \ne 1 $ .

Comment: Using your notations, I am getting $\zeta_\phi(-3)^2 = (z^2+4z+1)^2/(1-z)^8$. For $z=e^{i \pi/8}$, that value is $(1-i) \xi$, where $\xi \approx 45,013.022$, hence $\zeta_\phi(-3)^2$ is not real

Comment: @Sasha: thanks for the crosscheck; I've reproduced your result. You missed that leading $z$ in the formula; you needed to write $ \small \ldots = z^2 \cdot (z^2 +4z + 1)^2/(1-z)^8 $

Comment: Thanks, in this case you deal with $\zeta(\varphi, -n, 0)$ in wikipedia's convention, I used $a=1$ as stated in the title.

Comment: I see; I'll update the title. Unfortunately, in wikipedia the formula begins then with a division by zero, but this might go as minor notation problem then...

Comment: given that $s = -n$, the first term is $z^0*0^n$ which is perfectly defined in the case at hand.

Comment: In case this is helpful, the exponential generating function for $\zeta_\varphi(-n)$ is $(1-e^{t+i \varphi})^{-1} = \sum_{k\ge0} $\zeta_\varphi(-k) t^k/k\!$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the symmetry of the triangle of Eulerian numbers the rational function
$$R_{n}(z) = {z \over (1-z)} \cdot E(z,n) \cdot (1-z)^{-n} $$
satisfies$$R_{n}(z)=(-1)^{n+1}R_{n}(\frac{1}{z}).$$
Since the numerator and denominator polynomials of $R_{n}(z)$ have real (in fact,   integer) coefficients we have$$\overline{R_{n}(z)}=R_{n}(\bar z).$$
Your observation should now be explained (there is no need to restrict to $n>2$).

To clarify further:

Let $ z = \exp(i \cdot \varphi) \ne 1 $ lie on the unit circle so $\bar z = \frac {1}{ z}$ and let $n \geq 1$.
Suppose $R_{n}(z) =  a+ib$.

Then from the above$$\overline{R_{n}(z)}=R_{n}(\bar z) = R_{n}(\frac{1}{z})=(-1)^{n+1}R_{n}(z). $$  Hence $$a-ib = (-1)^{n+1}(a+ib).$$ If $n$ is even we get $a = 0,$ and so $R_{n}(z)$ is pure imaginary; if $n$ is odd we get $b= 0,$ and $R_{n}(z)$ is real.

A particularly interesting case is when $z = i$. The sequence $(2 \cdot R_{n}(i))n \geq 1$ equals $[-1, -1 \cdot i, 2, 5 \cdot i, -16, -61 \cdot i,...]$, which is the sequence of up-down numbers multiplied by powers of $i$. For more on this see my comment of Jan 2011 in A000111 in the OEIS.

Comment: thanks! For $R_n(z)$ *n=1* this can even be seen when z is explicitely written as $z=\alpha + \beta i$ and then multiplied out (exploiting $ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 1$ ) - the imaginary part vanishes then. But we still cannot allow *n=0* ; we have always $-0.5 + x i$ which is not on the real or imaginary axis.

Comment: Peter, what you define as $R_{n}(z)$ is $Li_{-n}(z)$ according to the last formula in [link](http://oeis.org/wiki/Eulerian_polynomials).

Comment: Nice. Or even simpler Table[I^(n+1)*2*PolyLog[-n,-I],{n,1,11}].

Comment: @Peter: again thanks; that clarification is nice and concise, so I think, I'd accept that answer. Btw, in my previous question I showed that same sequence (for $ \varphi=\pi/2$ ) only I did not yet expect, that it would be better to let the series begin with $z^1$ at the first term. (But I think it makes no sense to adapt that old question&answer)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't make Peter's answer fully transparent to me. So I tried two things; both led to a solution.
1) rewrite the $ \small \zeta _\varphi(-n) $ - expression based on the description via the Eulerian polynomials as taylor-series in terms of $ \small \varphi$, which is real. We can factor out $ \small i^n$ and stay with a series in $ \small \varphi ^2$, thus the result is $ \small i^n \cdot x$ where *x* is real.

2) Rewrite the expression using the Eulerian polynomials using $ \small z=exp(i \varphi)$
in $ \small \zeta _\varphi(-n) = {z \over 1-z} E(z,n) \cdot (1-z)^{-n} $

Factor out $ \small  {z \over (1-z)^2} $ to get as first cofactor
$\qquad \small  {z \over (1-z)^2} = {1 \over (1/\sqrt{z} - \sqrt z )^2} ={1 \over (\exp(- i \varphi/2) - \exp(i \varphi /2))^2 } 
 = {1 \over (-2 i\sin(\varphi /2))^2 } = -1/4 \cdot \sin(\varphi /2)^{-2} $.
This value is always real, and is also $ \zeta_\varphi(-1) $.

Then , for instance, for *n=3* we get for the remaining part of the formula:

$ \qquad\small \begin{array} {ll} (1 + 4z + 1z^2) \cdot (1-z)^{-2} &=& (1/z + 4 + 1z) \cdot (1/\sqrt{z} - \sqrt z )^{-2} \\\ 
 & = &(1 \cdot (1/z + z) + 4 ) \cdot -1/4 \cdot \sin(\varphi /2)^{-2} \\\
 & = & - ( {1 \over 2} \cos(\varphi)) + 1)\cdot \sin(\varphi /2)^{-2} \\\
 \end{array}$

Together this gives
$ \qquad \small \zeta_\varphi(-3)= 1/4 \cdot \sin(\varphi /2)^{-4} \cdot ( {1 \over 2} \cos(\varphi)) + 1)
$

Well, this is only for one *n*, but I begin to understand, how this works and why we get these purely imaginary/real results (and I even begin to see Peter's mentioned symmetries here.... )